# Is this study guide wrong about commands for determining file types?

Tags: linux, bash

The study guide *LPIC-1 Training and Preparation Guide* (Ghori Asghar, ISBN 978-1-7750621-0-3) contains the following question ...

> Which of the following commands can be used to determine the file type?
>
> - (A) `file`
> - (B) `type`
> - (C) `filetype`
> - (D) `what`

... and claims that the answer is: "(B) `type`".

But isn't "(A) `file`" the correct answer?

I'm beginning to doubt the entire book.

Comment: I have to say, a book which starts by saying “the exams are based on RHEL and Debian, so let’s use CentOS and Ubuntu” doesn’t inspire confidence!

Comment: You should contact the author and notify him of the mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it seems like your book is wrong.

The `file` command tells what kind of file it is. From the man file: "file -- determine file type".
A few examples:

```
$  file /usr/bin/file
/usr/bin/file: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=ecc4d67cf433d0682a5b7f3a08befc45e7d18057, stripped
$ file activemq-all-5.15.0.jar
activemq-all-5.15.0.jar: Java archive data (JAR)
```

The `type` command is used to tell if a command is built in or external:

```
$ type file
file is /usr/bin/file
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
```

Comment: `type` is a builtin on most shells, which tells us what something that can be executed is  (builtin, alias, function, executable, etc.). In your case it's saying there's no `test.sh` that can be executed (either in PATH, or as a builtin/function/alias, etc.).

Comment: You're absolutely right. I never knew that. Doesn't change the answer should be `file` though. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm glad I pirated the book lol

Answer (score 2):

The file type is normally determined with `file`. Its `man` states:

> file — determine file type

But you can also to certain extent use `type`. Compare the two listings below for:

- `script.pl`, a Perl script
- `not_a_script`, an empty file

Here's one for the script:

```
$ ls
script.pl
$ file script.pl 
script.pl: Perl script text executable
$ type script.pl
bash: type: script.pl: not found
$ type ./script.pl 
./script.pl is ./script.pl
```

And here's one for the empty file:

```
$ ls not_a_script 
not_a_script
$ file not_a_script 
not_a_script: empty
$ type not_a_script
bash: type: not_a_script: not found
$ type ./not_a_script
bash: type: ./not_a_script: not found
```

As you can see, `type` can determine if a file is executable. Is that a "determination of file type" or not? Well... In a different way to what `file` provides. The description of the `type` builtin in Bash's man is as follows:

> type [-aftpP] name [name ...]
>
> With no options, indicate how each name would be interpreted if used as a command name.

The correct answer to the question in the book should be in my opinion `file`, because that's what its `man` says, and that's what passing tests is about. Or in other words, my first choice is `file`.